# Given a topological space X, and a collection of open subsets V, can I claim that there exists a basis B for X, of which V $\subset$ B?

Tags: general-topology

I am currently working through Munkres' book on topology for fun. One of the exercises asks me to show that if I am given a topological space X and a subset of that space A where each x $\in$ A is contained in an open subset U of A, then A is open as well.

Earlier in the section I am given the definition that a subset Y of X is said to be open if for each x $\in$ Y there is a basis element B of a basis C s.t. $x\in B \subset Y$

I should be able to conclude that A is open if I relate B to U and Y to A in my problem.  However this requires my set V of all U to be a subset of some basis.  Can I automatically claim that such a basis must exist or do I need something more?  Thanks.

Comment: Well the set of all open sets is a basis for the topology

Comment: That seems like an unnecessarily involved approach. Think about what you know about arbitrary unions of open sets.

Answer (score 1):

You have it turned around. Suppose $\scr C$ is a basis for the topology on $X$. The fact that $U$ is open and $x \in U$ means that there is some $C_x \in \scr C$ such that $x \in C_x \subseteq U \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the topology on $X.$ That is, $T$ is the set of all the open sets.

Suppose $A\subset X$ and $\forall x\in A\; \exists U\in T\;(x\in U\subset A).$ For each $x\in A$ let $V(x)=\{U\in T: x\in U\subset A\}$ and let $U(x)=\cup V(x).$

Note that $x\in U(x)\subset A$ for each $x\in A.$

Each $V(x)\subset T$ so $ U(x)=\cup V(x)\in T.$  So $\{U(x):x\in A\}\subset T$ so we have $$\cup \{U(x):x\in A\}\in T.$$

$$\text { Now }\quad A=\cup \{\{x\}:x\in A\}\subset \{U(x):x\in A\}\subset A.$$ Therefore $A=\cup \{U(x):x\in A\}\in T.$

Comment: This answer avoids the axiom  of choice. With the axiom of choice , there exists a function $V:A\to T$ such that $\forall x\in A\;(x\in V(x)\subset A). $  Then $A=\cup _{x\in A}\{x\} \subset \cup_{x\in A}V(x)\subset A,$ hence $A=\cup_{x\in A}V(x)\in T.$